# jquery; $().css failing to update style of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rss

so I'm getting a div, supplied by an rss feed, and the styles are being changed, so the links within the div appear with a grey color instead of it's original blue style.
this comes from a style sheet included on the local page.

here's a snippet of the code I get from the rss feed;

```
...<td style="padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px; padding-bottom:5px; line-height: 150%">
   <a href="http://www.blah.co.uk/destinations/destination~GRJ~George/" target="_blank">
      <span style="color:0e6ac8;">
         <span style="font-size:12px;">
            <strong>Joburg-George</strong>
         </span>
      </span>
   </a>
</td>...
```

Note the inline color style over here; `<span style="color:0e6ac8;">`
This style is being overridden by the style in the stylesheet.
previously I just put some jquery after the included block, to change that color, but the team rejected my pull request as it was too specific;

```
<div id="marketing_block" style="padding-left:0px;margin-left:0px;width:890px;">
     <?php echo $marketing_content['post_content']; ?>
</div>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    $("#marketing_block a span").each(function(){
        $(this).css('color', '#0E6AC8');
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that the rss feed content will change from time to time, so I have to keep all the inline styling for all tags inside of the `#marketing_block` div.

update:
I just tried this and got no errors, but yet the links remain grey;

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    $("#flight_marketing_block").find("*").each(function(){
       //$(this).css('color', '#0E6AC8');
       var style = $(this).attr("style");
       if(style != undefined && style != ''){
          try{
              style = "'" + style.replace(/:/gi, "':'").replace(/;/gi, "';'").replace(/;/g, ",").replace(/\'\s/, "'").replace(/.[\'|,]\s?$/, '') + "'";
              alert("style: " + style);
              for(var index in style.split(',')){
                 $(this).css(index.split(':')[0], index.split(':')[1]);
              }

          }catch(e){
             alert("problem: " + e.message)
          }
       }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the style of RSS Feed box. bcoz it is inside iframe, and you cannot access element inside iframe without having id of that iframe, and id of iframe given by RSS feed is changes on every refresh